# Click next link after click first

Tags: jquery

I am trying to after click in the "State" and press "OK" I want to trigger the click in the next link ("a").

I am using:

`$("[data-name='city']").on("click", function(){
$("#table").find("[data-name='city']").trigger("click");}`

But it is going to the last item. I know the find() will look for every item and stop in the end.

I want to know how to use the trigger in the next link with data-name = "city" and avoid to go and in the last one.

Thank you ALL.

```
<table id="table">
   <tr>
      <td style="">
         <a class="editable editable-click" href="javascript:void(0)" data-name="state" data-pk="113" data-value="18">My State 001</a>
      </td>
      <td style="">
         <a class="editable editable-click" href="javascript:void(0)" data-name="city">City 001</a>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td style="">
         <a class="editable editable-click" href="javascript:void(0)" data-name="state" data-pk="113" data-value="18">My State 002</a>
      </td>
      <td style="">
         <a class="editable editable-click" href="javascript:void(0)" data-name="city">City 002</a>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td style="">
         <a class="editable editable-click" href="javascript:void(0)" data-name="state" data-pk="113" data-value="18">My State 003</a>
      </td>
      <td style="">
         <a class="editable editable-click" href="javascript:void(0)" data-name="city">City 003</a>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: can you add some id or class? to make the link uniqueness to other

Comment: with find you will trigger all links. When you would like to trigger the next link?

Comment: Just a suggestion, I would not use a tag name as id, like you used table. It will cause confusions.

Comment: @burkay, Yes, I know. It is just an example. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the first selector so that it stops on the next city element:

https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/

```
$('[data-name="state"]').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').find("[data-name='city']:first").click();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`$("#table").find("[data-name='city']")` will select all `data-name='city` in `#table`. You should use `$(this).closest('tr').find("[data-name='city']")` to find `data-name='city'` after clicked `data-name="state"` like following.

```
$('[data-name="state"]').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').find("[data-name='city']").click();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#table").find("a.editable-click:last").trigger("click");
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#table").find("[data-name='city']").trigger("click");
```

Will match all the selectors with the `data-name='city'`, you have more than one. It triggers all of them, including the last one.

Try this:

```
$("[data-name='state']").on("click", function(e){
    $(this).closest("tr").find("[data-name='city']").trigger("click");
});
```

Demo 
https://jsfiddle.net/6cn8h70s/